# rbenv/ruby-build and shared libraries (libruby.so)

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am trying to to use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) with [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build).

After seemingly successful installation of both tools and ruby version I cannot find the shared library **libruby.so**

Are there are any specific instructions that I have to give to rbenv/ruby-build when I am installing ruby?

Have tried with ruby **2.1.0** and **2.1.2**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's a `libruby-static.a` under rbenv dir. I guess there is no dynamic-link lib here.

Comment: @halfelf yep there is a static, however some of the the gems trying to link via dynamic link.  Was wondering whether there is an option to have it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When compiling Ruby from source, you need to set `--enable-shared` to build shared libraries. With Rbenv, you can try to set this in `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS` before installing Ruby:

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"
rbenv install 2.1.2
```

Or alternatively:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" rbenv install 2.1.2
```

Comment: This did the trick for me as soon as i 'export'ed the variable.

Comment: It should work without export when you put it all in one line.